# Why do I get a C26486 compiler error moving a deque to a vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I don't know how to avoid getting C26486 "Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to function" Warning in line 3

The code below compiles, but when I ask for all microsoft warnings, I can't find a solution.

`toks_` is a `std::deque<token>`, where `token` is defined as `using token = std::variant<int, double, std::string>;`. The function `operator<<(s)` takes a `string_view` and adds to the `toks_` deque.

```
std::vector<token> tokenizer::tokenize(std::string_view s)
{
    toks_.clear();
    operator<<(s);
    std::vector<token> ret{ toks_.begin(),toks_.end() };
/*
// Alternatives that give the same error.
    std::vector<token> ret;
    ret.reserve(toks_.size());
// Alternative 1
    for(auto it= toks_.begin();it != toks_.end();++it)
        ret.emplace_back(std::move(*it));
// Alternative 2
    for (auto&& tok : toks_) ret.emplace_back(tok);
// Alternative 3
    std::move(toks_.begin(), toks_.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
*/
    toks_.clear();

    return ret;
}
```

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Addition: Complete Demo Program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>

using namespace std::string_literals;

using token = std::variant<int, double, std::string>;

enum class token_type : std::size_t {
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    STRING
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{
    switch (static_cast<token_type>(tok.index())) {
    case token_type::STRING:
        out << std::get<std::string>(tok);
        break;
    case token_type::DOUBLE:
        out << std::get<double>(tok);
        break;
    case token_type::INT:
    default:
        out << std::get<int>(tok);
    }
    return out;
}

class tokenizer
{
public:
    tokenizer() noexcept {};
    void operator<<(std::string_view s);
    std::vector<token> tokenize(std::string_view s);

private:
    std::deque<token> toks_;
    const std::string delim_{ ",\"" };
    const std::string_view escape_{ "\"" };
};

void tokenizer::operator<<(std::string_view s) {
    toks_.push_back(1);
    toks_.push_back(-1.2);
    toks_.push_back("string"s);
    toks_.push_back(0);
}

std::vector<token> tokenizer::tokenize(std::string_view s)
{
    toks_.clear();
    operator<<(s);
    std::vector<token> ret{ toks_.begin(),toks_.end() };
    /*
        std::vector<token> ret;
        ret.reserve(toks_.size());
        for(auto it= toks_.begin();it != toks_.end();++it)
            ret.emplace_back(std::move(*it));
        for (auto&& tok : toks_) ret.emplace_back(tok);
        std::move(toks_.begin(), toks_.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    */
    toks_.clear();

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    tokenizer tok;

    std::vector<token> dummy{ tok.tokenize("Hello World!\n"s) };
    for (const auto& t : dummy) std::cout << t << "\n";

}
```

Output:

```
1
-1.2
string
0
```

Comment: I'm sure you could have written a tiny 4 line `main` function that duplicates the warning instead of posting code that is mostly commented and plucked out of a class function.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate this warning](https://www.godbolt.org/z/KLgLl8).  This is compiled using Visual C++, level 4 warning flags on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used "run code analysis on File." In the project properties I used "Microsoft all rules." Compiled under c++17 Visual Studio.

Comment: @davidbear I tried to run code analysis on File with rules as specified by you. I did not get the warning that you got, instead, i got Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26447 The function is declared 'noexcept' but calls function 'allocator<char> >()' which may throw exceptions

Comment: @riteshsangani I also get the C26447 error, but that one I understood.

Comment: This question is also asked in [Why do I get a C26486 compiler error moving a deque to a vector?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d915ce35-eb3d-4e2e-8257-cd1356270543/why-do-i-get-a-c26486-compiler-error-moving-a-deque-to-a-vector?forum=vcgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but now I know what. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.2.5, 
Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA505. I have enabled Code Analysis on build, and I have selected "Microsoft All Rules."

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> d_src;
    std::vector<int> dest{ d_src.begin(),d_src.end() };  // C26486
    std::vector<int> dest_c{ d_src.cbegin(),d_src.cend() };
    std::deque<int> dest2{ d_src.begin(),d_src.end() }; // C26486

    std::vector<int> v_src;
    std::vector<int> v_dest{ v_src.begin(),v_src.end() };
    std::deque<int> v_dest2{ v_src.begin(),v_src.end() };
    std::list<int> v_dest3{ v_src.begin(),v_src.end() };

    std::list<int> l_src;
    std::vector<int> l_dest{ l_src.begin(),l_src.end() };   // C26486
    std::vector<int> l_dest_c{ l_src.cbegin(),l_src.cend() };
}
```

I am still clueless about the error, but when the source is a vector or if I use constant_iterators, I don't have a problem. Comments still welcome.

Comment: Std::string_view is a type added in C++17 to serve some of the roles previously served by const char * and const std::string& parameters. Std::string_view is intended to be a kind of universal “glue” — a type describing the minimum common interface necessary to read string data. This gives you type erasure for “free”, as a function accepting a string_view can be made to work with any string-like type, without making the function into a template, or constraining the interface of that function to a particular subset of string types.

Comment: For more details I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/lifetime-profile-update-in-visual-studio-2019-preview-2/).
[Lifetime safety profile](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#prolifetime-lifetime-safety-profile)